# Adding order online feature to restaurant website

Tags: payment-processing

Hello everyone I’m reaching out to the community for help, I just got my first real world project. It’s a Restaurant the tools I used are HTML, and Bootstrap. And now the the restaurant owner wants to be able to take orders online, and my anxiety is going through the roof on how to handle this. I use Node.js for backend. The first thing that came to my mind was that I would have to use Stripe somewhere along the way. Please, I need some guidance on how to handle this step by step.

Comment: That is a lot to help with. My advice will be to go through the Stripe Docs for starters https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges

Comment: @Siddharth Bhansali stripe was already an option in my post, I want more of a plan